# Asympototic analysis for the following series sum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, asymptotics

I am wondering is there one way to extract the asymptotic behavior of $x$ in the following expression near $x=0$?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\log(1-\exp(-n x))$$ where $x $ is real.

Comment: At least the divergent parts of the asymptotic expansion seem like they can be extracted from the leading terms in the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula), see specifically the formula under "asymptotic expansion of sums."

Answer (score 2):

First, expand the logarithm into its Taylor series:

\begin{align}
S&\equiv \sum_{n\ge 1}n\log(1-e^{-nx}) \\
&= -\sum_{n\ge 1} n \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{e^{-knx}}{k} \\
&= -\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n\ge 1}n\,e^{-nkx}
\end{align}
To sum the inner series,
differentiate the following identity with respect to $\beta$,
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta}}-1=\sum_{m\ge 1}e^{-\beta m},$$
obtaining
$$\sum_{m\ge 1}m\,e^{-\beta m}=\frac{e^{-\beta}}{(1-e^{-\beta})^2}.$$
Identifying $\beta$ with $kx$ in our original series, we see that
\begin{align}
S&=-\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{1}{k} \left(\frac{e^{-kx}}{(1-e^{-kx})^2}\right)
\end{align}
Using $e^{-kx}=1-kx+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$,
\begin{align}
S&=\sim -\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k^3}\frac{1-kx}{x^2} \\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{k^{-2}}{x}-\frac{k^{-3}}{x^2}
\end{align}
Thus,
$$S\sim -\frac{\zeta(3)}{x^2}+\frac{\zeta(2)}{x}\qquad \text{as } x\to 0$$